# Как записать словарь в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Вот кусок кода:

```
pb = {'Егор':79, 'Коля':45}
f = open('pb.txt', 'w')
f.write(pb)
f.close()
```

При попытке запустить файл выскакивает исключение:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'.

Может существуют какие-нибудь обходные пути?

Comment: Каков должен быть результат? Приведите, пожалуйста, образец файла.

Comment: Файл — это последовательность байт, а не словарь. В файл можно записывать байты, но не словари.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

```
import pickle

data = {
    'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4 + 6j],
    'b': ("character string", b"byte string"),
    'c': {None, True, False}
}

# сохранение в файл
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

# чтение из файла
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data_new = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Или как json, но там, конечно, меньшее разнообразие типов, да и объекты классов просто так не запихнешь без предварительной сериализации...

Comment: @gil9red я думал добавить сохранение словаря в Json. Но не смотря на внешнее сходство, словарь и json объект ни одно и тоже, что только добавит путаницы в голову ТС.